# Calling Python script from salt scheduler

Tags: scheduler, salt-stack

I have written a salt scheduler and and the scheduler is running every minute. I want to call a Python script from the scheduler.

Any working example would be of a great help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a python script from a schedule you could use cmd.script. Here is a schedule state file as an example:

```
job3:
  schedule.present:
    - function: cmd.script
    - job_args:
      - salt://test.py
    - seconds: 3600
    - splay: 10
```